# last data entered cell index in a column

Tags: jquery, html

in a table how to find last data entered cell index in a column.
my table is like below

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 3, cell 1</td>
<td>row 3, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>row 4, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 5, cell 1</td>
<td>row 5, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>row 6, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 7, cell 1</td>
<td>row 7, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 8, cell 1</td>
<td>row 8, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>row 9, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>row 10, cell 2</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

in above table i want first column's last entered cell index thats is 8.
How to find it with dynamic expression using jquery..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking the first row last column

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJtG9/)**

```
$('tr:eq(1) td:last').index()
```

Edit based on comments by OP, To find the first not empty td starting from end.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJtG9/3/)**

```
tds = $('tr td:nth-child(2n+1)');
for(i=tds.length-1; i >=0; i--) 
    if($.trim(tds.eq(i).text()) != "")
        break;    
alert($(tds[i]).text());
```

Comment: it will not work. @Adil. as it will return the first TH tag, he wants last entered column.

Comment: it's returning first row last column but i want first column last data entered cell index

Comment: What do you mean by Last data entered cell index?

Comment: means first column last cell index which has data. In above example 9 th and 10 cells of first column dont have data.so want 8 as result.